# Combining basic mapping with custom logic

Tags: java, spring, dto, mapstruct

I have the following DTO:

```java
public class AccountDto {
  private Long id;
  private BigDecimal balance;
  private Currency currency;
}
```

and its corresponding entity:

```java
public class Account {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "id")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "balance", scale = 2)
  private BigDecimal balance;

  @Column(name = "currency")
  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  private Currency currency;

  @Column(name = "created_at")
  @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)
  @Builder.Default
  private Date createdAt = new Date();
  
  .
  .
  .
}
```

`Currency` is an `enum` of my own with maybe 300 currency symbols:

```java
public enum Currency {
  AFN,
  EUR,
  ALL,
  DZD,
  USD,
  AOA,
  XCD,
  NUC,
  .
  .
  .
}
```

I also have a utility called `CurrencyLedger` which has a method called `convertAmountToTargetCurrency` for converting a certain amount of money from one currency to another. Its implementation is not important for this question; just that it exists.

Here's my problem. I want to use `MapStruct` to implement `PATCH` logic for mapping fields from an `AccountDto` dto to an `Account` entity. `id` and `currency` can be straightforwardly mapped, ***but I want to avoid mapping them if they are `null`***. `balance`, on the other hand, needs a bit of since, if the `currency` is supplied by the dto, is different from the entity's and we DON'T supply a new `balance`, then the entity's existing `balance` needs to be adjusted through the method I mentioned above.

To achieve all this, I followed the advice from [here](https://www.baeldung.com/mapstruct) in section 5.2 to inject my `CurrencyLedger` class into an `abstract` class:

```java
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
@Component
public abstract class UpdateMapper {

    @Autowired
    protected CurrencyLedger currencyLedger;

    @Mapping(target = "balance", expression = "java(updateBalanceIfNecessary(entity.getCurrency(), dto.getCurrency(), " +
            "entity.getBalance(), dto.getBalance()))")
    @Mapping(target = "id", source = "dto.id", defaultExpression = "java(entity.getId())")
    @Mapping(target = "currency", source = "dto.currency", defaultExpression = "java(entity.getCurrency())")
    public abstract Account updateEntityFromDto(AccountDto dto, Account entity);
    
    protected BigDecimal updateBalanceIfNecessary(Currency entityCurrency, Currency dtoCurrency, BigDecimal entityBalance,
                                                  BigDecimal dtoBalance){
        // If the dto provides a balance, just use it and be done with it.
        if(dtoBalance != null){ 
            return dtoBalance;
        }
        // Otherwise, if the dto provides a currency that is different from the entity's, perform the appropriate conversion.
        if(dtoCurrency != null && dtoCurrency != entityCurrency){
            return currencyLedger.convertAmountToTargetCurrency(entityCurrency, dtoCurrency, entityBalance);
        }
        // Finally, if the dto either does not provide a currency or provides the same currency, return the entity's balance.
        return entityBalance;
    }
}
```

and, as you can see, I am calling the method `updateBalanceIfNecessary()` when the `target` is the `balance` field. On the other hand, for the fields `id` and `currency`, I have a `defaultExpression` of whatever the entity gives me, following the advice of [the same Baeldung article](https://www.baeldung.com/mapstruct), section 12. Effectively, if the `dto`'s corresponding `id` or `currency` are `null`, copy over the entity's field.

But this is effectively reproducing the problem for which we are using `MapStruct` in the first place. What if my classes had 100 fields? Would I add 100 `@Mapping` annotations?

I also tried annotating the method `updateEntityFromDto` by using `@BeanMapping` instead of the two extra `@Mapping` annotations, hoping that it would take care of all the fields except for `balance`:

```java
 @Mapping(target = "balance", expression = "java(updateBalanceIfNecessary(entity.getCurrency(), dto.getCurrency(), " +
            "entity.getBalance(), dto.getBalance()))")
    @BeanMapping(nullValuePropertyMappingStrategy = NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy.IGNORE)
    public abstract Account updateEntityFromDto(AccountDto dto, Account entity);
```

but in that case I get a compile-time message telling me that I haven't taken care of the `currency` and `id` fields:

[image: Several different source properties for fields message.]

So effectively, what I want is special logic for the `balance` field and default `null`-ignoring logic for *all* the other fields of my class. I don't want to have to write one `@Mapping` annotation per field that I simply want copied; that's what we want to use a solution like `MapStruct` in the first place. How could this be achieved?

Comment: BTW: by updating existing bean instances, you don't need to return the Account. You should use: https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#updating-bean-instances

Comment: then you can have control over null properties on update mapping method: https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#mapping-result-for-null-properties